# Server Architechture for Enterprice level application

Tags: security, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, webserver, rackspace-cloud

I have developed an enterprise level application(CRM), And planning to provide it as a SAAS/Hosted Solution.

I am very much worried about the Server & It's Architecture to handle the large traffic. I did some work and reached at, I can use AWS Or Rackspace Claude Service with Load Balancer, RDS, S3.

But still I am not sure it is enough to handle the large traffic or not. I have following questions please provide me some suggestion.

1. Is there any other good Cluod Service provider than AWS and Rackspace.
2. How to architect the server(Backup Plan, Highly Available, Data Base Server, Staging etc.)
3. Please suggest some tool to monitor the server performance.
4. Server Security.
5. Tools to calculate the server costing.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

1. Is there any other good Cluod Service provider than AWS and Rackspace. - There are options like Google Cloud, HP Cloud, SoftLayer, Azure and many more.
2. How to architect the server(Backup Plan, Highly Available, Data Base Server, Staging etc.) - Pretty big question to address.
3. Please suggest some tool to monitor the server performance. -- NewRelic can be one of them.
4. Server Security. -- Pretty big question to address.
5. Tools to calculate the server costing. -- https://planforcloud.rightscale.com/ - This would help.